# Error when querying a type with unfilled attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I created the schema and resources (the DynamoDB tables), and I also attached the needed resolvers. Here is the screenshot of the User table with some sample data.

Sample data
[image]

For the first user, there are only id and username. Other fields are empty. When I query this user in AppSync console, there will be some error.

Query Error
[image]

Here is the query I used:

```
query getUser{
    getUser(id:"5d0a2154-b828-4bcb-a34a-07503fe4b458"){
    id
    username
    userProfile{
      id
      lastName
      firstName
    }
    school{
      id
      schoolName
      schoolAddress
    }
    role{
      name
    }
    studentCourseSessions{
      id
      notes
    }
    programs{
      name
      courses{
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the VTL for the getUser query
[image]

Seems like, if a field is empty, there will be an error. I want, if the field is not filled, it should return "null". It can still return error but I need the "null" as well.

I am new to AppSync and DynamoDB.

Comment: Hi there and welcome, please add code that you have tried already, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will add the code in posting.

Comment: The error that is being returned "The provided key schema does not match..." indicates an issue with the mapping template. Can you post the VTL from the resolver for that query?

Comment: Thanks Rohan, I already posted the VTL for the getUser query